# bind() get "Invalid argument" error in Linux network programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets

This is my code

```
#include "basic.h"
#include "bp_socket.h"

int setup_tcp(char *port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    in_port_t server_port;
    int sock;
    int retval;                     //return value

    if ((server_port = atoi(port)) < 0)
    {
        server_port = (in_port_t)DEFAULT_PORT;
        fprintf(stderr, "Error port: %d in line %d\n", (int)server_port, __LINE__);
        //fprintf(stderr, "Use default port: %d\n", DEFAULT_PORT);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        return sock;
    }

    retval = listen(sock, 40);
    if (retval < 0)
    {
        return retval;
    }

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons(server_port);
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    retval = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    if (retval < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        return retval;
    }

    return sock;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", setup_tcp("4558"));
    perror("");
    return 0;
}
```

I debug my code, then I found `bind()` return `-1`

I google it and read man page, but I couldn't found my answer.

function `setup_tcp` is create socket, and bind with address.

then return `a socket` or `errno value`.

How to solve it. I had read my code for many times.

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is you have to call `bind` before `listen`.

Comment: `server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `listen` after the `bind`.

`bind` returns an error if the socket is already bound, and `listen` on an unbound socket automatically binds it to a random port number.